# Cython: Making an external C function accessible for other Cython modules

Tags: c, cython

If I have a C function `void foo()` in an external library, I can execute it in `module1.pyx` as

```
cdef extern from "fooHeader.h":
    void foo();
...
foo()
```

However, can I make this function public for other Cython modules, without using a wrapper function?

For example, using a `module1.pxd`:

```
cdef extern void foo()
```

does not make the function available in a `module2.pyx`:

```
from module1 cimport foo
foo()
```

which aborts with an undefined symbol error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way is to make a wrapper, since you usually want to intercept types and such when you expose such functions to *Python* code. Off the top of my head, probably the easiest way for you to accomplish what you're after is to use Cython's *include file* facility, with `.pxi` files:

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/language_basics.html#include-file

A snippet from the link:

> How do I use it?
>
> - Include the .pxi file with an include statement like: include "spamstuff.pxi"
> - The include statement can appear anywhere in your Cython file and at any indentation level
> - The code in the .pxi file needs to be rooted at the “zero” indentation level.
> - The included code can itself contain other include statements.

So you would put the `cdef extern <...>` stuff into the `.pxi` file and include that in all your users.

(Side note: I can't remember whether you can expose the extern modules via a `.pxd` interface file or not.  That *might* also work, but I haven't checked.)